# Swift iOS : Delete UITextField with button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm creating a textfields in viewDidLoad and i have a add new textfield button. I'm adding new textfields, but not deleting. I just don't do it because i am new. Here is my addNewTextField button func :

```
 @IBAction func addNewTextField(sender: AnyObject) {
        var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 200.00,height: 240.00));
        myTextField.placeholder = "write something"
        myTextField.center = CGPointMake(160, CGFloat(height2))

        height2 = height2 + 50;

        self.arrayOfTextFields.append(myTextField)
        self.view.addSubview(myTextField)

    }
```

How can i delete this textfields and arrays with another button ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you trying to delete the last text field, the first text field, or a specific text field?

Comment: Use `removeSubview:` to remove the subview.

Comment: I tried `self.view.removeFromSuperview`, but it didn't work. It is delete all subviews. And i didn't find removeSubview sorry.

Comment: You don't want to remove your ``view`` from its superview, but your ``textfields`` from their superview.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new func or IBAction and create a loop to go through all of the elements in self.arrayOfTextfields.  You can then grab each textfield from the array and remove it from the superview.  When the loop is finished, you can clear the array.

Something like this:

```
for textField in arrayOfTextFields {
    textField.removeFromSuperview()
}

arrayOfTextFields = []
```

Comment: Ok, we are really close to right answer now. Good to delete all arrays, but not to textfields. I am creating a textfield when the app starts. I want to delete textfields except these.

Comment: The textfields that you initially add and want to keep, do not add them to the arrayOfTextfields and they will not get removed, unless there is another reason you need to add them to the array, let me know.